# Focus on a object element in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a list coming from

```
  var validator = $("#myform").validate({ /* settings */ });
            var errors = validator.errorList;
```

now in errors list i want to focus on obj at zero index
But problem is these objects are in different divs how can i focus on this and make active that particular dic because the div are inactive.

I have tried this

```
        errors[0].element.focus();
```

but apparently my div of that particular element is hide how to open that or show that particular Div

For Example i have this div and this div is inactive/hide, first i want to make active this div and focus on a element in this div which can be text box or dropdown

```
 <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab_1_8">

                                    <h3 class="form-section">Other Info</h3>
                                    <!--/row-->
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="control-label col-md-3">Operating Instructions</label>
                                                <div class="col-md-9">
                                                    @Html.DropDownList("SIGNING_ID", null, "Select Signing Authority", new { @class = "form-control" })
                                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SIGNING_ID)
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="control-label col-md-3">Residential Status</label>
                                                <div class="col-md-9">                                                                                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CNIC_NICOP, new { @class = "form-control", @data_val = "true", @data_val_required = "CNIC/NICOP/POC is required", @data_val_regex_pattern = "^[0-9-]*$", @data_val_regex = "Please Insert only numbers" })
                                                  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RESIDENTIAL_ID)
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

Comment: Show the parent div and set it top ,you can focus your element then .

Comment: how to find that parent div? and how to make it show?

Comment: `validate` is your plunge method ?

Comment: yes validate is my plugin method jquery.validate

Comment: this plunge has a `focusInvalid` option to do this , you don't need to do it yourself.

Comment: yeah i have try this but actually my div of that particular invalid element is hidden i just want to make it show

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122955/discussion-between-mussaib-siddiqui-and-passion).